# Regex String matching using .equals Method

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to match two string using following lines

```
int row = 1;
String index = row + ",(.*)";
String R = "1,2";
Object result = index.equals(R);
```

The result is false while I want it to be true.I cannot use other method link .matches() and not even the pattern object for the index as i want it to integrate with other method which uses Hashmap .

In the map keys (String) will have indexes link (1,2) , (1,3) , (2,3), ... I want to search them from the first number i.e 1 , 2  and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `String#equals` doesn't invoke a regex engine, it does an exact comparison.  If you need regex functionality, then you'll have to use `String#matches`, or use a `Pattern`.

Comment: `The result is false while I want it to be true.` — you won't get this expression to return `true` in Java ;)

Comment: Please add an example of how you use it with `HashMap`. You can't change `String.equals()` implementation.

Comment: Why are you declaring result as Object when it is a boolean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986031/how-to-use-pattern-matcher-in-java might prove useful, even if it is referencing HTML regex parsing (which is a bad idea) - "matches" only works if it completely matches the pattern. You want partial matching - you'll need a Matcher object for that level of detail.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change `String.equals()` behaviour. If you insist to get `true` use:

```
Object result = !index.equals(R);
```

Comment: This is a pure mockery :)

Comment: Or `Object result = true`

Comment: @m0skit0 but wouldn't this be a premature optimisation? :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be

```
boolean result = R.matches(index);
```

or

```
boolean result = R.startsWith(row + ",");
```

Now a HashMap has no sorted keys, however there is a Map that also is a SortedMap, namely TreeMap:

Instead of

```
Map<String, T> map = new HashMap<>();
```

do

```
SortedMap<String, T> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

As `"1," < "12,"` given that `',' < '0'` the standard String comparison suffices.

Then receiving the [sub-map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#subMap-K-K-) of a row is possible:

```
String firstKey = row + ",";
String lastKey = row + "/"; // As '/' > ','

SortedMap submap = map.subMap(firstKey, lastKey);
```

This submap is *backed* by the original map, that is, changing it will change the map.

It should be said, that the keys seem a bit artificial, maybe row + another field in a RowKey class, or `Map<Integer, Map<String, T>>` (row map first) would make more sense.